# Can i use Xtion Pro Live outdoors

Tags: opencv, asus-xtion

I am working with Xtion Pro Live on Ubuntu 12.04 with Opencv 2.4.10. I want to do object recognition on daylight.

So far i have achieved object recognition indoors by producing a depth and a disparity map. When i go outdoors the maps that i mentioned above are black and i cannot perform object recognition.

I would like to ask you if Asus Xtion Pro Live can work outdoors.
If it cannot, is there a way to fix it (through code) in order to do object detection outdoors?

I have searched around and i found out that i should take another stereoscopic camera. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

After some research I discovered that the Xtion Pro Live stereoscopic camera, can not be used outdoors because of the IR sensor. This sensor is responsible for the production of depth map and is affected by sunlight. Because of this, there are no clear results. Without clear results the creation of depth and disparity map (with the proper values) is impossible.